# Checking website for a link using PHP

Tags: php, url, web-crawler

I am building a script on my website but find myself a little confused how to get this to work well with minimal coding.

Basically all that is needed is so i can input a url for instance, domain.com and it should scan that homepage for a link that points to my domain and also check and see if rel="nofollow" is assigned or not and return true if the link is there with no rel="nofollow" or false if no link, or a link with rel="nofollow" on it.

How would i go about this, or where would i start.

I've googled how to create a spider but its all far to much information and complex for a basic script i am trying to create!

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for isn't as simple as you might think.  To do this properly, you need to use a DOM parser, such as `DOMDocument`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

You can use its [loadHTML()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) method to parse the web page you want to scan through.  From there, you can use its variety of functions to find the specific link you're looking for, and check its attributes to make sure the URL is correct, and your `rel="nofollow"` is in there.

I assure you that in the end, this is much easier than just a string search for your URL.  Going down the blind search road will lead you to inaccurate results, and will be much more of a hassle than you realize.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/.](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```